# how to infer parameters passed to a function correctly when it depends on a runtime value

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have the following function with its proper types you can pass:

```js
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
type _ExclusifyUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
    T extends unknown ? Id<T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>> : never;
type ExclusifyUnion<T> = _ExclusifyUnion<T, AllKeys<T>>;

type PropsRoot = {
    common: string;
}

type PropsA = PropsRoot & {
    a: number;
    onPress?: () => void;
}

type PropsB =  PropsRoot & {
    b: number;
    onPress?: () => void;
}

type PropsC =  PropsRoot & {
    c: number;
}

type PropsD = PropsRoot & {
    d?: string;
    onPress: () => void;
}

type Props = ExclusifyUnion<PropsA | PropsB  | PropsC | PropsD>;

const fun = (props: Props) => {}
```

The type tells the caller that it should send `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` but not them together. Plus, some type allows `onPress`, whereas the latter `PropsD` requires it.

Basically, the type I get is the following one, where one Property excludes the props that should not be blended:

```js
type Props = {
    common: string;
    a: number;
    onPress?: (() => void) | undefined;
    b?: undefined;
    c?: undefined;
    d?: undefined;
} | {
    common: string;
    b: number;
    onPress?: (() => void) | undefined;
    a?: undefined;
    c?: undefined;
    d?: undefined;
} | {
    common: string;
    c: number;
    a?: undefined;
    onPress?: undefined;
    b?: undefined;
    d?: undefined;
} | {
    ...;
}
```

When it comes to static types everything works good, but if the type depends on a runtime value, the inference of course it's more generic, and I can't tell "hey, in some case I could pass you PropsA or PropsD, nothing more":

```js
const test = true;
fun({common: 'common', a: test ? 2 : undefined, onPress: () => {}});
```

to make it work, I should explicit say that `b` will always be `undefined`, which I would like to avoid the consumer to do:

```js
fun({common: 'common', a: test ? 2 : undefined, b: undefined, onPress: () => {}});
```

Is there a better way to define this and get what I want to describe with this interface, even with runtime conditions involved?

Here is the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=51&ssc=1&pln=51&pc=83#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA0hEBnAPAFQHxQLxSZQQAewEAdgCapQCuFA1hQPYDuFUA-FIyiwDNCUAFxQKEAG4QATgG4AUKEhQAklSy4CRUuWq0AlhQGyoAVW5QA3lADaiKEd78hZgLpiz9t1AC+o8SlZRWVoAH0AURIAYzg6VAMBEDMKAxYKLAAaKAddShooAAUZFkgZUGQQLQUoWuE8-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-qgp6theV43gopFlCY0TAAAdGoo49BQoK9hAULdiwtH0SI7E4RBqHcdBH6HjBUAAMyYdhD5cQR6GfiZpn8dqv7-megGiRi4ldjSdBTn2nAGKC0LMuSUAyAwQ5QtAFZUAFlzdkcqDREiYCgkYJgyLQPTxSovaDpO660Kwvl5aoClKQoFZVuQVYEIidAQIolncdZq7QXu1Wgjw+4BAwcwCEYEBULZvUQP1EhDZq35OYJf4tue8GkaVY5Kd2PYGLQwAaUVmlwGIaWmD0tAZvmOZWj0PkvoOw6DHAIBAA) to play it around

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. the last type is inferred as `{ common: string; a: number | undefined; b: undefined; onPress: () => void; }` and it compiles

Comment: So... [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgQqbm)? Otherwise, I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: oh right XD `b` should be set based on `test` too